# How can I drop commits in the git log if it isn't letting me?

Tags: git, github, gitkraken

I'm trying to delete and remove the commits highlighted in the picture. However when I do interactive rebase and drop the commits it just makes the strand more complicated. How can I have one line of commits without the ones that I highlighted? By the way, some commits might have the same message but their source code is completely different. Please suggest both gitkraken and CLI git solutions.

[image]

This is the diagram I am sort of looking for
[image: git log diagram]
EDIT
This is the updated diagram
[image]

Comment: I can't tell the difference between your two masters. I"m assuming one of them is a remote branch?

Comment: Interactive rebase is how to do it. Show your code and the result if you have questions about what you're doing. Note that interactive rebase necessarily _duplicates_ all subsequent commits, so if that's what you're worrying about, you can stop worrying.

Comment: @xdhmoore yes one of them is local and the other is the remote file

Comment: @matt ive tried dropping the commits that i highlighted however it doesn't let me. Like i want to remove them completely and merge every thing to the side inside the master branch.

Comment: I don't know what those words mean. Perhaps you could draw a diagram of the history you want.

Comment: @matt I posted a diagram

Comment: Ah, I see why it won't let you rebase; it's because that's the remote-tracking branch. OK, I've asked the wrong question. Ignore the remote-tracking branch completely; you're going to have to overwrite it with force anyway. Instead, draw a diagram of how you want `master` to go, starting with "broadcasts typing". When you've got that you can just replace `origin/master` with it.

Comment: @matt I see, the blue stream is already uploaded on github and all that is my local repository is "user typing feature v2: fixed empty input bug" and all the commits that follow.  My question is there a way where i can get those two files i have in the diagram and delete the rest? Or unmerge and just drop what I need to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thing to know: `origin/master` (the second master in your diagram) is not yours. It is the *remote-tracking branch* whose sole job is to reflect what's on GitHub. It is effectively the medium through which you fetch / pull and push. You cannot directly edit the remote tracking branch `origin/master` at all. The real `master` is yours, though.

So the first thing you need to do is get those commits onto a real branch, and we may as well use `master` itself as the real branch:

1. On `master`, make a new branch to hold your place; let's call it `temp`.
2. Now, still on `master`, do a `reset --hard` down to "removed console logging" (the higher one in the diagram). We have deliberately skipped past the unwanted merge commit, so it's going to be eradicated later along with the other "removed console logging".

Okay, now all the earlier commits you want to reshuffle are on `master` and we can do our reshuffle:

1. Rebase interactive starting at "broadcasts typing", and drop "user typing".
2. Now `git cherry-pick temp`, and then force-delete the `temp` branch; you no longer need it.

Now `master` looks the way you want!

So now you can push, thus reconciling the remote-tracking `origin/master` to it; but you will have to use force because you have rewritten history. This has serious (possibly disastrous) consequences if you are sharing this branch with others, but those consequences were implicit in the question as posed and there's nothing we can do about it.

The *real* moral of this story is, *don't push* the main branch until your history really is the way you want it. If you don't know whether your history is settled, use more branches to experiment until you *do* know. Having to rewrite what you already pushed to GitHub is a really bad smell and suggests your work habits are incorrect.

Comment: okay, right now i have a temp and master branch pointing to the merge commit. When i do a hard reset all it does is move my HEAD and branch to "removed console logging". The merge commit still stands. I updated the picture to show

Comment: Yes, but don't worry, when we force push at the end, it will be forgotten.

Comment: This is after I hard reset into "removed" and the merge commit wasnt gone. Is it because it is still linked with the blue stream?

Comment: Yup, as I said, our force push at the end will fix all of that. Right now the goal is to get you in a position to do your interactive rebase.

Comment: Ok now I have:

"removed console logging" (the right one),
"synchronize user typing",
"broadcasts",
and the rest. 
Everything else is on the blue stream, and you said after the push that those contents will be gone?

Comment: After a force push, the remote-tracking `origin/master` will look exactly like your `master` looks now. In fact, they will be _the same branch_ (at least for that moment). That is what force pushing means. — Don't forget about that extra commit currently known as `temp` (the real "user typing feature"). You don't have to rescue it now, it's safe, but don't forget about it.